# draw pair of scissors in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is there someone who can help me to draw a pair of scissors in latex? 
The picture below is good enough. I have no problem with constructing the rings, but I don't know how to make the "body"? I have very bad experience in typing in latex, this is by first time. Please help anyone.

[image]

Comment: This question shows no research effort at all. If you do not know, how to use TikZ, you should include a figure or a symbol like in my answer. If it is so easy for you, to do the rings, why don't you show your code then. I guess, the PGF-manual explains how to draw a wedge or a line. And a fill as well. I am going to vote for closure as this is not TeX related but a "do-my-work-for-me" post.

Comment: I would be as simple as just making some circles. \draw circle is the function I would use. Yes, I know it seems like it, but I don't know where to start. I only know how to draw lines e.g.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 11):

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{code2000.ttf}\symbol{"2702}
\setmainfont{quivira.otf}\symbol{"2702}
\setmainfont{symbola.ttf}\symbol{"2702}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you are on pdfLaTeX:

[image]

---

Included in TikZ:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (scissors) {\Leftscissors};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it did not work. I am writing a paper, and I am using report, not article, is this a problem? I want to have the pair of scissors in a tikzpicture, because I want to draw something more than just the pair of scissors.

Comment: @Eirik "it did not work". What does that mean? Please read http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to just scale the scissor, but the the whole tikzpicture?

Comment: @Erik It is just text, so you can put `{\Huge\Leftscissors}` or alike in the node label. Or you set a scale or text width as option to the node. E.g. `\node[scale=3]`

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Thank you, I really appreciate it! This would have taken me a long time to find out!